# StrComp function in excel vba is giving wrong result.

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying data to a cell on the basis of some condition.

```
If (StrComp(Trim(sh333.Cells(i333 + 1, jHistory).Value), Trim(sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, jHistory).Value), vbTextCompare)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "history Comments and Last comments are Same / Equal"
            sh44.Cells(counterFinalHistory, 7).Value = Trim(sh333.Cells(i333 + 1, jHistory).Value) '& vbNewLine & sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, 3).Value & ":" & sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, jHistory).Value & vbNewLine & sh333.Cells(i333 + 5, jHistory).Value & ":" & sh333.Cells(i333 + 4, jHistory).Value 
            sh44.Cells(counterFinalHistory, 8).Value = Trim(sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, jHistory).Value & vbNewLine & sh333.Cells(i333 + 5, jHistory).Value & ":" & sh333.Cells(i333 + 4, jHistory).Value)  
        Else
            MsgBox "history Comments and Last comments are Not Same / Different"
            sh44.Cells(counterFinalHistory, 7).Value = Trim(sh333.Cells(i333 + 1, jHistory).Value & vbNewLine & sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, 3).Value & ":" & sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, jHistory).Value & vbNewLine & sh333.Cells(i333 + 5, jHistory).Value & ":" & sh333.Cells(i333 + 4, jHistory).Value) 
            sh44.Cells(counterFinalHistory, 8).Value = Trim(sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, 3).Value & ":" & sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, jHistory).Value & vbNewLine & sh333.Cells(i333 + 5, jHistory).Value & ":" & sh333.Cells(i333 + 4, jHistory).Value)  
        End If
```

There are 2 disturbing trends here:

1) The strings in the 2 cells sh333.Cells(i333 + 1, jHistory).Value And sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, jHistory).Value are exactly equal still StrComp goes in the Else part and says that "history Comments and Last comments are Not Same / Different"

2) Also when I am copying the the contents of sh333.Cells(i333 + 1, jHistory) to sh333.Cells(i333 + 2, jHistory) then StrComp behaves correctly and says "history Comments and Last comments are Same / Equal"

Please do let me know the reason for this erratic behaviour of StrComp function of VBA. I have broken my head over this but found nothing to correct the behaviour. Please do help and suggest.

Comment: If copying one cell to the other causes the `StrComp` to then say that they are the same, the chances are that they weren't the same to start with.  What tests did you do to make you think that they were the same?  (E.g. if you just eyeballed them, you may have missed a difference in two characters that display the same.)

Comment: Could you please edit your Question to add the exact values of each cell and also exactly how each cell is formatted?  Ctrl-1 brings up cell properties, as you may know.